# how to introduce 2 inputs into a matlab block function that processes only one variable at a time?

Tags: mobile-robot, pid, matlab, dynamics, simulation

Using SIMULINK, I wanted to optimize 2 variables with the ant colony optimization algorithm; which is written in a matlab function block, the function is of type function y = f (x) it has only one variable to optimize and since I have 2 variables! how can i do ?
[image]

Comment: this exact question has been asked  before ..... is this a school assignment?

Comment: But I have not had a answer yet dear jsotola

Comment: On your [other question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/16814/9720) **I told you** `It's not possible to give you any more help than that because, as @N.Staub mentioned, you haven't linked the package you're using, the function you're using, the error you're getting, or what you're trying to do.` I also suggested you write what appears to be costing values into one cost *function* so you can weight/assign the costs appropriately. Then I said for you to **edit your question to include some information** so we can help you.

Comment: I let that question stick around for **four days** before I deleted it. You never came back to post any follow-up comments, you never made any edits to the question, you didn't say if you were having trouble making a cost function, no mention of the optimizing function/package you're using, what you're trying to do, etc. **Please edit your question to provide some relevant information** other than "I want to do this thing that I can't do."

Comment: Thank you @Chuck for your repply :                                                           
 Invalid setting for dimensions of input port of 'vehicle_animation_sim/Demux'. The Demux cannot be used to split matrices
Component:Simulink | Category:Model error
Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'vehicle_animation_sim/MATLAB Function' is a [5000x7] matrix.

Comment: @Student62 - That error appears to state that the *output* of your Matlab function can't be fed into a demux because it's a **matrix** and not a **vector**. Your Matlab function should almost always **not be outputting a matrix** inside Simulink; it's akin to having an entire solution generated *on every step* of a `for` loop. This error does *not* pertain to getting values *into* the Matlab function, which is what your text seems to ask for. You also haven't included the code that's in the Matlab function or the toolbox from which it originated, there's no Simulink diagram, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Chuk
But how to solve this kind of error, and even we must optimize an objective function containing more than one variable while the matlab function contains only one input and one output as for example optimize a position p (x, y) so you have to take the combination x, y optimal and not optimal x and optimal y each separately and sometimes there will be other variables also such as time etc ...